# Why is __weakref__ removed by default when __slots__ is used?

Tags: python, weak-references, slots

I think the main purpose of `__slots__` is to save the memory usage by allowing to specify properties explicitly, instead of using `__dict__` allowing dynamic property assignment on the instances. So I somehow understand why `__dict__` is removed by default when using `__slots__`. But why does it meanwhile remove `__weakref__` by default?

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't read minds, but I suspect the rationale goes like this:

1. If `__weakref__` wasn't disabled by default when using `__slots__`, providing a way to save the associated memory explicitly would require yet another special opt-out mechanism
2. More special cases add complexity to the language, and this one would provide no real benefit

Given how infrequently weak references are used at all, it was probably deemed simpler to simply have it disabled by default, with the option to opt back in.

Diving to implementation details, in a sense, unslotted user-defined classes have precisely two "slots" (one for `__dict__`, one for `__weakref__`) over and above the base object header, so having `__slots__` say "Replace the default with this explicit list" makes it natural to remove both `__dict__` and `__weakref__` when `__slots__` comes into play.